# Minimize $x$ in factorial division

Tags: number-theory, factorial

My question is that how can we find the smallest natural number, $n$, such that some other number, $x$, divides $n!$. What I mean is that what minimum $n$ such that $x\mid n!$ for $x,n\in \mathbb N$.

My thoughts on this were that, we know that when we have divides, there exists some other variable, say $y$, then we have $y(n!) = x$. But how do we minimize the value of $x$?

Comment: If $x=p$ is a prime number, then $n=p=x$.

Comment: @Larara What if it isn't prime

Comment: If $x=p_1\cdot\ldots\cdot p_n$ (all the exponents are $1$) is the factorization of $x$ with $p_1<\ldots <p_n$, then $n=p_n$.

Comment: @Larara What if $x=25$ where the exponents aren't all $1$?

Comment: If $p$  is a prime divisor of $x$ and $p^k$ is the largest power of $p$ that divides $ x$, then for $x|n!$ we need $k\leq \sum_{m\in N} [n/p^m]=V(n,p), $, where $[y]$ denotes the largest integer not exceeding $y,$ because $p^{V(n,p)}$ is the largest power of $p$ that divides $n!$.

Comment: @user254665 could give us some references on this function $V(n,p)$?

Comment: @Larara. I just made up the "$V$" so as not to  re-type the summation in the exponent of $p^{V(n,p)}$..... .$ [n/p]$ counts the number of multiples of $p$ that don't exceed $n$. And $[n/p^2]$ counts one more for each multiple of $ p^2$ that doesn't exceed $n,$ etc.  Wikipedia has 2 articles : Legendre's Formula, and  de Polignac's Formula, both about this same formula. You can also find it as Legendre's Formula  in the Wikipedia article Factorial.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, we have two cases where the result is clear. They are

1. If $x=p$ is a prime number, then $n=p$;
2. If $x=p_1\cdot\ldots\cdot p_n$ is the prime factorization of $x$ with $p_1<\ldots<p_n$, then $n=p_n$.

Now, for the general case, write $x=p_1^{e_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_n^{e_n}$ again with $p_1<\ldots<p_n$. Let $p$ and $e$ be the prime number and the exponent, respectively, such that $e\cdot p=\text{max}_i\; e_i\cdot p_i$. If $e<p$, we have that $((e-1)\cdot p)!$ does not divide $x$, because $p$ in the prime factorization of $((e-1)\cdot p)!$ appears only $(e-1)$ times, but we have that $(e\cdot p)!$ clearly, once $e\cdot p=\text{max}_i\; e_i\cdot p_i$. It is not difficult to see that no number $r$ such that $(e-1)p\leq r<ep$ will be such that $x\nmid r!$, because $p$ in $r!$ will not appear $e$ times. Hence, we conclude that $n=e\cdot p$. For example, if $x=25=5^2$, we have that $2\cdot 5=10=n$. If $e\geq p$, then things start getting complicated. Let's take a look at some simple cases.

Consider $p=2$. Below, at the first row, I have listed the first few multiples of $2$, and at the second row, the exponents of $2$ in the prime factorization of the corresponding multiple.

```
2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40
1,2,1,3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 3
```

Now, let's do the same thing for $p=3$.

```
3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60
1,1,2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1
```

If, for a fixed prime $p$, we call by $\{A_{p,i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ the sequence of the exponents of $p$ appearing in the multiples of $p$, i.e., $A_{p,i}=\{\text{exponent of}\; p\;\text{in the prime factorization of}\; i\cdot p\}$, then, it is not difficult to see that

$$A_{p,k} =\begin{cases} 1, & \quad\text{if}\;k\neq0\,\text{mod}\,p \\ j, & \quad \text{if}\;k=0\,\text{mod}\,p^{j-1}\;\text{but}\;k\neq0\,\text{mod}\,p^{j} \end{cases}$$

For, $p=2$ and $p=3$, the first few terms of $A_{p,i}$ are at the second rows of the above sequences, respectively.

So, back to the question, if $e\geq p$, our $n$ must be such that $n!$ contains exactly (or, to be more precise **at least**) $e$ times the prime $p$ in its prime factorization. But, note that, if we take $n=e\cdot p$, then the prime $p$ will appear **at least** $e+1$ times at the prime factorization of $e\cdot p$. For our $n$ to be the least integer such that $x|n!$, we'll have to find **the least** $N$ such that

$$e\leq\sum_{i=1}^N A_{p,i}$$

and then, finally, our $n$ will be given by $n=N\cdot p$. I suggest you to analyze several cases with small primes such as $2,3,5$ and $7$.

Comment: So what I get from this logic is that in the general case, we basically multiply the largest prime factor with its power. Correct?

Comment: Not exactly, you have to take $\text{max}_i\;e_i\cdot p_i$. For example, if $x=5^3\cdot 3^2$, you have $3\cdot 5=15>6=2\cdot 3$, so in this case $n=3\cdot 5=15$. If, for example $x=3^4\cdot 6^2$, we have $4\cdot 3=12=2\cdot 6$, so $n=12$.

Comment: One last thing. For the last example in the comment above, $3^4\times 6^2 = 2916 = 3^6\times 2^2$ so wouldn't it be 18?

Comment: @user318919 disregard the last example, $6$ **is not** a prime number. Another thing, my answer does not fully answer your question.